# colocar em negrito a primeira palavra do paragrafo HTML

Tags: html5, css3

Queria saber como colocar a primeira palavra de um paragrafo em negrito. Estou usando o arquivo reset.css.
Já tentei usar <b> </b> e tambem <strong> </strong> , mas nada acontece.
Também tentei usar font-weight: bold; porem nesse caso ele deixa o paragrafo inteiro em negrito e eu só gostaria de deixar uma palavra

Answer (score 4):

por CSS as opções mais proximas do que você deseja são os seletores :first-letter (primeira letra) e :first-line (primeira linha), para seu caso acredito que apenas cercando a primeira palavra manualmente/programaticamente com uma tag (como strong):

```
<p><strong>Primeira</strong> palavra em negrito</p>
```

Exemplo de código JS para dividir primeira palavra do resto do texto:

```
var texto = "Primeira palavra em negrito";
var ispace = texto.indexOf(' ');
if (ispace >= 0) texto = [texto.substr(0,ispace),texto.substr(ispace)];
else texto = [texto];
//texto = ["Primeira", " palavra em negrito"]
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Essa resposta é só um *workaround* com CSS for fun :)</sup>

Tem uma gambeta bem loca que da para fazer só com CSS, é até elegante, mas tem um ponto contra, se vc selecionar o texto a primeira palavra fica parecendo que não foi celecionada, mas se vc der um <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> vai pegar o texto certinho...

O que eu fiz foi passar o mesmo nome da primeira palavra para um atributo `data` direto na tag, e no CSS eu usei um `pseudo elemento` para colocar o negrito. Não sei se vai economizar muito tempo, mas pode te ajudar...

```js
//esse script é só para vc ver como fica o elemento e o texto dele no DOM

var p = document.querySelectorAll('p')

console.log(p[0],'\n',p[1]);
```

```css
p {
  position: relative;
}
p::before {
  content: attr(data-bold);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p data-bold="negrito">Negrito lorem ipsum dolor!</p>

<p data-bold="rapaz!">Rapaz! Que doidera</p>
```

Comment: e que "gambeta", isso vai fazer algo como criar uma DIV cobrindo o texto de baixo, dependendo das fontes usadas, a versão bold, pode acabar ocupando mais espaço que a normal e engulir um pouco além da primeira palavra ... '-'

Comment: @anon sim é vdd rss, bem observado, pode acontecer principalmente em fontes mais oblíquas, e tbm não daria certo se o texto estiver sobre uma imagem, o fundo tem que ser liso 